# Database updates Out of date

Tags: updating

I downloaded a couple of module updates. Before I did so, I didn't disable the modules. Is this ok? I am now seeing the following in my Status Report:

Database updates    Out of date
Some modules have database schema updates to install. You should run the database update script immediately.

Is it safe for me to run the database update script now? Or should I first do a core update (am currently running 7.18 and would be upgrading to 7.19)?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/250790

Comment: You should run the database update script each time you update one or more modules, or Drupal core, as a general rule. You can check the Status report page if there are any updates required.

Comment: Thank you PatrickKenny and @enzipher
I am logged in with the first account created on my site but going to update.php doesn't give me the link to "run the database upgrade script" eg: http://drupal.org/files/upgrading-10.png
How do I get to this screen: http://drupal.org/files/upgrading-13.png ?

Comment: That screenshot is from Drupal 5. Just go to `/update.php` and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Go ahead and run update.php.  It will run the updates (which are usually but not necessarily schema updates) for the new modules.

There is no need to disable modules before updating them.  There is no need to update Core first.  You *should*, however, put the site into maintenance mode before updating the modules until after you run update.php.

You should run update.php every single time you update a module or the Core.